# Ubuntu freezes on startup

Tags: boot, 20.04, thinkpad

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on a Lenovo Thinkpad X1. I had the laptop on suspend a few days ago, turned it back on and tried to log in using my fingerprint. The computer froze for several minutes and I ended up doing a hard shutdown; when I tried turning it back on it froze before reaching the splash screen: I just got the white "Ubuntu" on black background and then nothing for several minutes.

I restarted with REISUB, went into recovery mode and opened a root terminal. Forced an fsck on next reboot and then I did manage to get it running.

After this I worked for a bit, shut the PC down normally, and now turning it back on I have the same problem as before, but what I did before doesn't seem to change anything. I turned off the quiet splash option in grub and now I get all the messages at startup. Everything seems OK, but then it gets stuck at "finished TLP system startup/shutdown.".

Is there anything I can do to try to fix this? I can log onto a root terminal and get any kind of information that could be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After many hours of trying, of running fsck both on startup and with a liveusb, I logged into root and just ran update and upgrade. The problem seems to be fixed now but startup feels slower.